# Запуск другого JFrame и закрытие текущего

Tags: java, swing, gui, jframe

Есть два JFrame они расположены в разных пакетах (соответственно, и разных классах). На одном - графическая заставка, на другом - меню программы. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку (в окне заставки) открывалось окно меню программы?

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, у вас заставка в пакете `test` на фрейме frame, а сама программа в пакете `program` на фрейме `newframe` в классе `NewClass`.

Как уже сказал zRrr, для закрытия одного `JFrame` и открытия другого вам достаточно сделать:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // слушатель на нажатие кнопки
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.setVisible(false); // закрываем текущий фрейм
        program.NewClass.newframe.setVisible(true); // открываем следующий фрейм
    }
});
```

Либо обратиться к функции в классе `NewClass`, которая у вас создаёт новый фрейм и сама делает его видимым.

---

Чтобы открыть новый `JFrame` через некоторое время, если юзер не кликнул на мышь, например, можно воспользоваться таймером:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            program.NewClass.newframe.setVisible(true);
        }
    }, 
    5000 // таймер на 5000 мс = 5 секунд
);
```